# groupBy and addGroupBy does not group up

Tags: query-builder, typeorm, pgadmin

I am trying to group products with deleted and non deleted items, but code does not work(also not crushes), tried to group by categories but still does not work... any idea?

```
const sales =  await getRepository(Sales)
        .createQueryBuilder('sales')
        .where("sales.selfMerchantId = :id", {id: user.id})
        .groupBy("sales.deleted_at")
        .addGroupBy("sales.id")
        .withDeleted()
        .getMany();


    return sales;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two group by attributes mentioned in the query `sales.deleted_at` and `sales.id` makes each attribute of the result set unique. I would rather write two different queries with where clause to get deleted and non deleted records.

**Update 1**

I verified that ORM is returning an expected response with the above query. In the response, I am getting non deleted records first and then deleted records.

Comment: so it will be 2 request to db and i don't wont it, i achieved same result with foreach, but i think there should be something to achieve with just one query

Comment: I verified that ORM is returning an expected response with the above query. In the response, I am getting non deleted records first and then deleted records.